# Select de 3 tabelas relacionadas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho as seguintes 3 tabelas:

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM Cartao
INNER JOIN Registo 
ON Registo.ID_Cartao=Cartao.ID_Cartao
INNER JOIN Clientes 
ON Registo.ID_Cliente=Clientes.ID_Cliente
WHERE Clientes.ID_Cliente=Registo.ID_Cliente
AND Clientes.ID_Cliente=2
```

Com este *select* consigo ver os cartões que estão registrados com o cliente com ID 2.
Eu gostaria de saber qual o *select* para ver os cartões NÃO REGISTRADOS do cliente com id 2.

Comment: Note que a condição expressa na cláusula WHERE (Clientes.ID_Cliente=Registo.ID_Cliente) é a mesma condição da junção e portanto totalmente redundante e desnecessária.

Comment: O que seria "Eu gostaria de saber qual o select para ver os cartões NÃO REGISTRADOS" ?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a teoria dos conjuntos numéricos aplicada ao banco, a maneira correta e mais performática de obter o resultado seria essa:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cartao
left JOIN Registo 
ON Registo.ID_Cartao=Cartao.ID_Cartao
left JOIN Clientes 
ON Registo.ID_Cliente=Clientes.ID_Cliente
AND Clientes.ID_Cliente=2
WHERE Clientes.ID_Cliente is null
```

Você fará apenas uma seleção utilizando da logica de conjuntos conforme abaixo:
[image: Conjunto numerico aplicado a banco]
https://eufacoprogramas.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/SQL-Joins-1024x819.jpg

Aproveitando, não entendi o motivo de no Where você colocar a mesma condição que utilizou no join `Clientes.ID_Cliente=Registo.ID_Cliente` e

```
Registo.ID_Cliente=Clientes.ID_Cliente
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Cartao
INNER JOIN Registo 
ON Registo.ID_Cartao=Cartao.ID_Cartao
INNER JOIN Clientes 
ON Registo.ID_Cliente=Clientes.ID_Cliente
WHERE Clientes.ID_Cliente=Registo.ID_Cliente
AND Clientes.ID_Cliente NOT IN (2)
```